# Rounding-up a decimal to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, rounding

I have a problem to round a number to two decimal places.

I have the number 3106.4647771976413339683766317M.

The correct round to two decimal places is 3106.47, but using `Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` the number is 3106.46.

The problem is the method look to third decimal place to round, but if it look to fourth decimal place will generate the correct number.

Someone has something like that?

Comment: But... looking to the third decimal place is what it's supposed to do. 0.464 should be rounded to 0.46 since the third digit is below 5.

Comment: if are trying to round `.4647` to `.47`. its not really a round in the normal sense. most people would be confused at this

Comment: https://www.factmonster.com/math-science/mathematics/rounding-numbers-rules-examples-for-fractions-sums

Comment: Rounding `x` up to 2 decimal places is the same as rounding `x + 0.005` to the nearest with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Anyway, you need to justify this statement "*The correct round to two decimal places is 3106.47*"  and show us the exact rules of what you need. Otherwise there is no way to answer this question

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, the correct round to two decimal places *is* 3106.46.

What you probably want is a *ceiling*:

```
Math.Ceiling(3106.4647771976413339683766317M * 100) / 100
```

produces 3106.47. There is no version of `Math.Ceiling` accepting a number of decimal places, that's why there are multiplication and division.

In addition, note that there is a caveat in this expression:

```
Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

`Math.Round` does not have a variant with three arguments, where the first one is a `decimal`. It works, because the value is implicitly converted to `double`. However, this is unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to round that way (more of a common mistake than actual rounding in the traditional sense) you can round up from the furthest right digit and move left one place at a time.

```
double numberToRound = 3106.4647771976413339683766317;

int placesToRoundTo = 2;
int smallestPlaceIndex = 24; // you would need to determine this value

for (int i = smallestPlaceIndex; i >= placesToRoundTo)
{
    numberToRound = Math.Round(numberToRound, i, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

There isn't a simple built-in method to do this because it isn't normal rounding.

Comment: There is — `Math.Ceiling`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Math.Ceiling returns the closest integer, it does not let you choose where the rounding happens. I see in your answer how it could be used to achieve the desired behavior, but on it's own it does not do what the question asked, and your solution limits the range of numbers that can be converted without overflow or precision errors depending on the places you want to round to, granted the reduction in range is pretty small for most common cases.